# CASE WHEN conditional in HiveQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, conditional-statements, hiveql

I'm having trouble bringing a case then into HiveQL.

I have a column with data:
if column is NULL = FALSE
if the column is PEOPLE = TRUE. It returns all results as TRUE.

What's wrong with my role?

```
SELECT 
    id,
    datetime,
    CASE 
        WHEN tb_people !="" THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'
    END
 FROM <BD>.<TABLE>
```

Comment: If all results are TRUE, it means there are no empty strings or NULLs in your column because NULL will trigger ELSE part, as well as empty string

Answer (score 1):

`!=""` is only checking for blank strings. `""` and `NULL` are two different things. As such, what you're looking for is:

```sql
SELECT 
    id,
    datetime,
    CASE 
        WHEN tb_people IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'
    END
 FROM <BD>.<TABLE>
```

I'd also recommend using the boolean `true` and `false` rather than string literals. This would let you replace your entire case statement with `ifnotnull(tb_people)` https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r3.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/vector/expressions/IsNotNull.html.